# input type file is Firing Twice onchange()

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have this script

**Update:**

```
/*on document ready*/
$(function() {
UploadFile();
}

function UploadFile(){
    $('#formarea').on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
        var input = $(this),
        numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
        alert('test');/*this showing two time*/
    });
    $('#formarea').on('fileselect','.btn-file :file', function(event, numFiles, label) {
        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
        log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;
        if( input.length ) {
            input.val(log);
        } else {
            if( log ) alert(log);
        }
    });
}
```

and i have this field on the form:

```
<form id='formarea'>
<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Documento Adjunto:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 has-warning">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                                            <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                                                buscar&hellip; <input id='file' type="file" name='i_file_1'>
                                            </span>
                                        </span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that onchange is firing twice the `alert`/ `alert('test');`  / of javascript is showing two time.
I need the state on input filled with a file to start a filter file extention.

Comment: The answer is probably quite obvious. You've wrapped your event handlers in a function called `UploadFile`, and you're calling that function more than once, binding the event handlers multiple times

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems these don't need to be wrapped in a function. You can instantiate them on document ready and achieve your desired outcome, like so:

```
$(function() {

    $('#formarea').on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
      var input = $(this),
      numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
      label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
      input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
      alert('test');
  });

  $('#formarea').on('fileselect','.btn-file :file', function(event, numFiles, label) {
      var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
      log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;
      if( input.length ) {
          input.val(log);
      } else {
          if( log ) alert(log);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: not because i need charge this event only on ajax callbacks.. when the document have add the input file because it i have insert on a function that i can refresh every time i have reload the form....

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering the second event which essentially does the same thing inside the first event. Try changing your events to functions and consolidating them under one ".on('change'" event.

```
$('#formarea input').on('change', function() {
    //Do stuff here
});
```

Comment: the second event is a different event, just the first when the file is selected, do not understand why you say it is for this reason that the event is repeated onchange

Comment: You trigger the 2nd event here input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]); causing it to fire twice